# Microsoft Access as web DB

Tags: ms-access

I know, we are in 2011 and not in 1998. But a customer asked to make a web site in ASP vs. an Access DB. I've read many bad things but I would really like what are the limitations of Access (after 2003) and the real reasons why not to use it (are their limitations on max concurrent user access? Is it unscalable? Breakable? etc.).

Comment: Surely you have other options? Jet/ACE is not designed for use in the context of a web server, and while you can get by with it with applications that have low numbers of users and are mostly read-only, it's still not the best choice. It's generally not going to be cheaper, either, so there just isn't any reason at all to go with it. It also is harder to backup and maintain, too, which makes it a drawback (because it's always going to be open, and thus not accessible for proper maintenance/backup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Access 2010 to build websites with Sharepoint: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Otherwise, it is unlikely to be a good idea, unless you are thinking of a private website, it which case it is do-able, with care, but still, not necessarily a good idea.

[This document contains an interesting table of limitations etc](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aRzdhJyEYqGoJ%3adownload.microsoft.com/download/5/d/0/5d026b60-e4be-42fc-a250-2d75c49172bc/when_to_migrate_from_access.doc+microsoft+access+concurrent+users&hl=en&gl=ie&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi02OflKwMKlVPbagtO05KKHWzHOGPsyYb6fDysPFunp88QO7tUS_LTkqdM5AcBbozcCX8Dp_GDFiksHeeT2TZndZfBZVWVBVBFxZW27tMnxQcxLPagGDdcWSEJVNIGizLiM7wd&sig=AHIEtbRpJy7eEfUC2oqi_3RqDkMb2lXTwg&pli=1)

Comment: the customer wants to create an ecommerce site ... so i think that users could be a good number; i'm very worried about it.

Comment: @Cris I have added a link to a useful document that may help you convince your customer.

Comment: thank you very much for the doc, really useful, i will forward it to the customer !

Answer (score 1):

If the website is mostly read only with relatively few inserts/updates then Access will work reasonably well.  One example might be a real estate website where a few listings per hour are added/updated.

Comment: The OP added a note to say that it is for an ecommerce site, which suggests quite a bit of security will be needed in addition to quite a lot of updating.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with @Remou that an ecommerce site is really outside the bounds of where a Jet/ACE data store is even marginally appropriate.

Comment: An ecommerce site would not be at all suitable.  Among other things, and I weasel worded this wehn I stated "reasonably well", if there is a database corruption all orders will be lost since the last backup or while the corruption is being dealt with.  This is, of course, totally unacceptable for an ecomerce site.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking MS Access is not appropriate for a large scale application. However it is just fine for smaller applications which doesnt handle many users simultaneously. Often MS Access is disregarded if the application has 10+ simultaneous users.

I dont know if it has a max connections, but I have heard that 16 is the limit, but others say 20 and some say there isnt a real limit

Comment: In my opinion I'd suggest that Access is unsuitable for 25 to 50+ users.    the strict limit on connections is 255 but that's not very practical.